# What is Show state icon in omnibox in Google Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, google-chrome

What is Show state icon in omnibox in Google Chrome?
During the installation of plugin for backspace key, I found there "Backspace Shortcuts for Linux"
I found there three options *viz.*
Activate Backspace for navigation in history object
Show state icon on omnibox
Close actual tab on top of history object (experimental)

What does the "Show state icon on omnibox" there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling "Show state icon on omnibox" will always show you the operable icon on address bar ( a.k.a Omnibox) as here

[image]

The right to Red ABP is your icon . The extension simply uses Keyboard Backspace Button to go to your previously visited section of the webpage you are currently active.

Answer (score 1):

It may be for omnibox application icon of chrome.
Not quite sure about it.